# US server for PHP & static file, UK server for MySQL (need suggestion)

Tags: networking, performance

I have 2 servers: one in US, one in UK
both servers are good hardware and connected with unmetered 100Mbps tier-1

but because US server is always give better search engine positioning, I'm going to setup server in US for PHP & static file, while server in UK for MySQL.

What do you think of my situation? Is this good decision?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to be blunt, but absolutely not. It's a horrible decision.

With your php server on one side of the pond and the database on the other, each database call is going to be subject to the latency of the transatlantic internet connection. This will easily add ~100ms to each query. Say on average that each page load generates 50 database queries - well you can do the math and see that this is not a good solution. You'll be penalized far more by Google et. al. for having a horribly slowly-loading website than you will for hosting your server in the UK (which, by the way, I would question your assertion that US-hosted sites will always get better ranking).